# .htaccess фаил поможет в google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

> Google analytics выдал отчет на 312 страниц, а их по факту 60. Откуда он их берет? Как эти страницы убрать? Индексируются ли страницы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htaccess править тут не нужно. У Вас переходы на сайт через рекламу,
`yclid` это параметр яндекс директа. Если вам не нужны эти данные в google analytics, то можно игнорировать этот параметр в построении отчетов.
[Тут подробнее как это сделать.](https://www.ru.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Otchety-i-analiz-Google-Analytics/Otchet-po-stranitsam-Kak-obrezat-UTM/td-p/186995)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! Буду проверять.